# Upper bound on volume growth on Riemannian manifold

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, volume

Let $M$ be a Riemmanian manifold such that for all $x\in M$ and large $R>0$, $$Vol(B(x, R))\leq \exp(R).$$ Let $p\in M$ and $d$ be the geodesic distance. Suppose that for large enough $r$ and all $x, y\in \partial B_{r}(p)$, $$d(x, y)\leq c\log r.$$ Is it then true that there exist constants $N>0$ and $C>0$ such that for all large enough $r$ we have $$Vol(B(p, r))\leq Cr^{N}?$$

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In more details, we can pick $D>1$ be so that $\text{Vol}(B_R(x))<e^R$ for ALL $x$ whenever $R\geq D$.
Take the first integer $L>1$ so that $L>e^{D/c}$, then $c\log L>D$.
For any $s\geq L$, note $2c\log s-c\log s=c\log s\geq c\log L>D>1$.

Take $x\in \partial B_s(p)$, observe
$$
\{z\,|\, s\leq d(z, p)\leq s+1\}\subset B_{2c\log s}(x);
$$
in fact, for any $z$ with $s\leq d(z, p)\leq s+1$, take a minimal geodesic $\gamma$ from $p$ to $z$, then $z=\gamma(t)$ with $t=d(z, p)\in [s, s+1]$, so there is a point $y=\gamma(s)\in \partial B_s(p)$ so that $d(y, z)=d(\gamma(t), \gamma(s))\leq 1$. Now $d(x, y)\leq c\log s$, so
$$
d(z, x)\leq d(z, y)+d(y,x)\leq 1+c\log s\leq 2c\log s.
$$

In particular, let $N=2c+1$, we see
$$
\text{Vol}(\{z\,|\, s\leq d(z, p)\leq s+1\})
\leq \text{Vol}(B_{2c\log s}(x))\leq e^{2c\log s}=s^{2c}=s^{N-1}.
$$

Let $C_1$ be so that $\text{Vol}(B_L(p))=C_1L^N$.
Now for any $r>L$, let $k$ be $L+k\leq r<L+k+1$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Vol}(B_r(p))\leq &\text{Vol}(B_L(p))+\text{Vol}(\{z\,|\, L\leq d(z, p)\leq L+1\})\\
&+\text{Vol}(\{z\,|\, L+1\leq d(z, p)\leq L+2\})+...\\
&+\text{Vol}(\{z\,|\, L+k\leq d(z, p)\leq L+k+1\})\\
\leq & C_1L^N+L^{N-1}+(L+1)^{n-1}+...+(L+k)^{N-1}\\
\leq & C_1L^N+(k+1)(L+k)^{N-1}\\
\leq & C_1(L+k)^N+(L+k)^{N}=(C_1+1)(L+k)^N\leq (C_1+1)r^N.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!